# Removing file from the last commit

Tags: git

How can I remove a file from my last commit, but keep everything else? Please note that I haven't yet pushed anything to a remote repository, so I just have to do this locally.

My workflow:

- Edit a few files
- Accidentally create a new file named `untitled.txt`
- Commit everything
- Notice the unwanted `untitled.txt` file
- Delete it
- ???
- Live happily ever after

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily change whatever you like in your last commit (messages, files, etc) with [`git commit --amend`](http://evadeflow.com/2011/04/git-commit-amend/).

So you would do something like this:

```
git rm untitled.txt
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail? Can I somehow `git add untitled.txt` the deleted file to the last commit so it would cancel itself out? The command doesn't work for adding deleted files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about a command `rm` up until now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the very next commit delete the file? It is typically considered bad practice to edit a commit history, and there is no shame in just removing the file in a subsequent commit.

```
git rm untitled.txt
git commit -m "Woopsy"
```

Comment: This is one solution, but it will leave trash in the history of the repository.

Comment: I'm hard pressed to consider mistakes trash... I think I just like have a pristine copy of the true history of a project.

Comment: @Ben I'd say coding mistakes are not trash, but mistakes in git are "meta mistakes" and not part of the project's "true history?" Just my two cents.

Comment: I think one big advantage of a DVCS like Git is you can massage the "unpublished" history locally and make it looks good before pushing to public.  I don't see it is a bad practice to edit commit history as long as the history is still local

Comment: If the trash is too large to push to Github, or it contains passwords -- those are two good reasons to amend.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine if you want to not only remove the file from the last commit, but completely.

But what if the creation of the file is not accidental, only the addition of that file to the commit?

If you want to just delete the file from the last commit, but keep the file in your working copy so that you can `git add` it to another commit, you can add `--cached` to the `rm` command:

```
git rm --cached wanted-for-another-commit-but-not-this-one.txt
git commit -a --amend
```

Now verify that it's gone from the commit:

```
git show -p   # no more diff between /dev/null and the file!
```

Verify it's still there:

```
ls -l wanted-for-another-commit-but-not-this-one.txt
```

Verify it's in the list of untracked files, eligible for a `git add`:

```
git status
```

Basically what we have done is removed the file from the index of staged files, while keeping the working copy. The `git commit -a --amend` command is aware not only of changes in the working copy, but in the index also. It notices a removal from the index and propagates that change to the newly rewritten commit.